# Reference own username in git-alias

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I want to list all commits 'since my last commit'.

Right now i use this log-alias variant:

```
[user]
    name = My Name
[alias]
    lg = !git log --since $(git log --pretty=format:'%ct' --author 'My Name' -1)
```

That works fine in general - but i would like to actually reference my username stated in the .gitconfig instead of hardcoding it.

Is it possible to access that value? (e.g.: `$(GITCONFIG:User:Name)`)

Just in case: `$(whoami)` does not work because the usernames don't match.

Comment: Quick Solution: `lg =!git log --since $(git log --pretty=format:'%ct' --author \"$(git config --get user.name)\" -1)` -- Thanks to @torek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract your name from your Git configuration:

```
me=$(git config --get user.name)
```

for instance.  Once you have that in a variable, you can refer to the variable.  (If you only need it once you can nest `$(...)` constructs, which is pretty clever-looking but may be hard to debug later :-) )

Hence:

```
[alias]
    lg = "!me=$(git config --get user.name); \
      git log --since $(git log --pretty=format:'%ct' --author \"$me\" -1)"
```

(you don't need the backslash-newline-indent sequence here, but you can use it if you like it: Git allows multi-line aliases using backslash-newline).  Note: semicolon is a comment marker in a Git configuration file, so if using one, we need quotes.

Comment: thanks a lot! yes it is harder to debug but this made my day:
`lg =!git log --since $(git log --pretty=format:'%ct' --author \"$(git config --get user.name)\" -1)`

Comment: I forgot to quote the whole outer thing - semicolons are comments in git config lines...